# rsa e, d, Φ(n) generation in js is not working

Tags: javascript, rsa

I am trying to do rsa cypher in js. I am trying to generate all keys but I have trouble with doing inverse of `e` which is `d`. I need to meet condition where `e*d ≡ 1 mod Φ(n)` -> `e*d mod Φ(n) = 1`. I generate 2 keys `p` and `q` that are prime numbers then multiply them.

`Φ(n)` is `(p-1)*(q-1)` then I pick `e` as prime number. Then I need to find modInv of `e`. After that I log `e*d mod Φ(n)`. It should be `1` but it isn't. I am using [`BigInteger.js` from `peterolson`](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/). I will put my code here.

```
  const lowNumber = (10**9);
  const highNumber = (10**10) - 1;
  let e = 2n;
  for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    let primeNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (highNumber - lowNumber + 1)) + lowNumber;
    while (isPrime(primeNumber) !== true){
      primeNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (highNumber - lowNumber + 1)) + lowNumber;
    }
    if(i === 0){
      pKey.value = primeNumber;
    } else{
      qKey.value = primeNumber;
    }
  }
  let n = BigInt(pKey.value) * BigInt(qKey.value);
  let fiN = BigInt(BigInt(pKey.value) - BigInt(1)) * BigInt(BigInt(qKey.value) - BigInt(1));
  let range = (fiN-1n) - BigInt(2);
  while (true) {
    e = BigInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * Number(range)) + 2);
    while (isPrime(e) !== true){
        e = BigInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * Number(range)) + 2);
    }
    let number = bigInt.gcd(e, fiN);
    if (bigInt(number) == 1n) {
        break;
    }
  }
  let d = bigInt(e).modInv(fiN)
  d = BigInt(d);
  console.log("inverse is: " + bigInt(e*d).mod(fiN)) //should be 1 but its not;
```

What am I doing wrong? It is usually like this:

```
e: 3482175725493151
d: 8070088128150463488
Φ(n): 14098658575081146888
inverse is: 1479924683334589200
```

I tried putting

```
if (bigInt(number) === 1n) {
        break;
    }
```

but it doesn't work so I had to leave `==` don't think this is causing it

Comment: Maybe your code for `isPrime` is wrong? Your mixing of bigInt and BigInt is extremely confusing and hard to read.

Comment: You should use `BigInt` consistently to avoid hard-to-debug precision problems. (That means generating random ones with rejection sampling, for example, like `BigInt(randHex32() + randHex32() + …, 16)` where `randHex32 = () => (Math.random() * 0x100000000 >>> 0).toString(16).padStart(32, '0')`.)